# Is there another bug when updating?

Tags: miktex, updating, miktex-update

[image]

Self explanatory.

Is this another bug?

Comment: Yes, I get it too. I made a bug report: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2602/

Comment: According to miktex.org this will be fixed on 24th May.

Comment: Bug reports are considered off-topic for this site. They should be sent directly to the maintainers of the programs and packages.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug that has been reported and will be fixed.