# MiKTeX FNDB Refresh Causes Kile LaTeX Build Error

Tags: errors, miktex

I have noticed odd behavior where after refreshing the FNDB from the MiKTeX options, I am unable to use Kile to build my TeX files.  When attempting to compile a TeX file it fails on the LaTeX step and doing a system check through Kile indicates that LaTeX is broken.

The source of the problem is that Kile is using FNDB files from the "%localappdata%\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\data\le" path but MiKTeX doesn't update these files when you perform a FNDB refresh.  The consistent way to solve this issue is to therefore go to that folder and delete all the files there.  After doing so, when I try to use Kile to build my TeX files it regenerates the FNDB files in that folder and all subsequent attempts to compile LaTeX files succeed until I refresh the FNDB again from MiKTeX.

I'd like to understand why I have to manually go into this folder and delete those files every time after I refresh the FNDB from MiKTeX.  Is the problem associated with MiKTeX or Kile?  Would clearing the settings/configuration of either one of them potentially solve the problem?  If so, where are the configuration files?

I am on a Windows 10 system using the latest version of MiKTeX 2.9 and the Kile editor incorporated with KDE on Windows (https://sourceforge.net/projects/kde-windows/).

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Maybe this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371203/is-there-another-bug-when-updating) is linked.

Comment: The version of MiKTeX I have was downloaded today after the MiKTeX repositories were brought back online with the fix for the bug talked about in that question.

Comment: I have no idea why Kile should need or use files from miktex. Do you have a multiuser miktex? If yes are you refreshing the FNDB in the miktex settings for the user *and* the one for the admin?

Comment: Your comment pointed me in the right direction.  Yes, I was using a multiuser version of miktex and using the Admin version of the MiKTeX options to refresh the FNDB is what breaks LaTeX.  Using the regular version of MiKTeX options to refresh the FNDB results in LaTeX building without errors.

Answer (score 1):

After also trying this scenario out with TeXworks (which pointed me to a helpful MiKTeX log), I found that while the Admin version of MiKTeX options remains open after the FNDB refresh MiKTeX cannot access the FNDB files under %localappdata% because it is being used by another process (likely the admin MiKTeX options itself).  Obviously this lock-out would result in errors when trying to build with LaTeX.

In direct contrast, having the non-Admin version of MiKTeX options open does not lock those same FNDB files after performing the refresh which is why LaTeX compilation proceeds without issue in that case.